# Communication between components by service not working

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-changedetection

I'm using the `BehaviorSubject` class to update the number of notifications in my global.
I have 2 components: the component notification shows a list of notifications and you can set these notifications as read.
The header component shows the number of notifications who are not read to let the user know that he missed something on the website.
Since there are 2 different components, I'm using a service to communicate through them.

Here are some snippets:

### notification.service.ts

```
export class NotificationService {
     public notification: BehaviorSubject<Object> = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
     public nbNotificationsChange: BehaviorSubject<number>;

constructor(){
     this.nbNotificationsChange = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
}

updateNbNotification(value) {
    this.nbNotificationsChange.next(value);
    this.nbNotificationsChange.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
}

getNbNotification(){
    return this.nbNotificationsChange.getValue();
} }
```

### header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    public notifications: Notification[] = [];
    public nbNotifications: number = 0;


    constructor (public notificationService: NotificationService){
    this.notificationService.nbNotificationsChange.subscribe(value => {
            this.nbNotifications = value;
        });
    }
ngOnInit() {
    this.getNotificationsNotRead();
    this.notificationService.nbNotificationsChange.subscribe(value => {
        this.nbNotifications = value;
    });
}

ngDoCheck(){
    this.nbNotifications = this.notificationService.getNbNotification()
    //console.log("test");
}
getNotificationsNotRead(){
    aNotRelevantFunctionToRetreiveNotification.subscribe(
            this.notifications = //Receive an array of Notifications here with some code
            this.notifications = this.notifications.filter((notif : Notification) => notif.seen == false); // Check if a notification is read or not
            this.notificationService.updateNbNotification(this.notifications.length);
            console.log(this.notifications.length);
    );
}

get nbNotif(): number {
    return this.notificationService.getNbNotification();
} }
```

### notification.component.ts

```
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {

public notifications: Notification[];

constructor(public notificationService: NotificationService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllNotifications();
}

public getAllNotifications() {
    //Receive an array of notifications to display them, passing this code. We're in the subscribe
    var nbNotifNotRead = this.notifications.filter((notif : Notification) => notif.seen == false).length;
    this.notificationService.updateNbNotification(nbNotifNotRead); //This value is properly set
}
}
```

Problem is, even if the value is set on notification.component.ts side, the value retrieved in the header.component.ts is not the good and is the initial one, witch is not what I want of course.

Does anyone have an idea? Been struggling on this for too much time now

### Update

Here is the html part, which is very simple:

```
<span class="SomeCSSClasses" *ngIf="nbNotifications > 0">{{nbNotifications}}</span>
```

### Update 2

The module involved:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
/* A lot of imports */

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    CurrencyService,
    /* A lot of services */
    NbNotificationService
    ]
})

export class ServicesModule { }
```

This is the original module that is imported in App.module.
What I through of is creating my own module like this:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';

import { NbNotificationService } from './nb-notification.service';
@NgModule({
  providers:    [ NbNotificationService ]
})

export class NbNotificationServiceModule {
    constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: NbNotificationServiceModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
          throw new Error(
            'NbNotificationServiceModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only');
        }
      }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
          ngModule: NbNotificationServiceModule,
          providers: [
            {provide: NbNotificationService, useValue: 0 }
          ]
        };
      }
}
```

Tried to add this to AppModule but it says an error like:

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NbNotificationService ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule PagesModule in ./PagesModule@-1:-1

Comment: `nbNotificationsChange` isn't defined in your class. Is that normal ?

Comment: Also, you subscribe in the ngOnInit() but never unsubscribe (you don't have an ngOnDestroy()) which you should be doing.

Comment: @trichetriche Oopsie, here it is (updated), forgot to include it in my snippet

Comment: @rrd idd, I forgot it too. But I tried differents subscribe at different place and the result is the same

Comment: Updated with the html for header.component

Comment: Where do you register the notification service? Is it provided by a module or by each component?

Comment: By a module @hagner

Comment: Is the module loaded lazy or eagerly?

Comment: lazy @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your services is provided in a lazy-loaded module and you want an application-wide singleton, you need to implement `.forRoot()` and provide the service there and import the module in `AppModule` with `MyModule.forRoot`.

Because DI contexts can't be modified after being created, lazy loaded modules get a new context for its providers and only this module and other modules loaded as part of it will be able to see the same instances of providers. `AppModule`, non-lazy loaded modules and other lazy-loaded modules will get no or a different instance.

See also https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#forroot

Comment: This service is registered in a global module service.module.ts. how can I apply .forRoot to only the service notification without his own module ?

Comment: Umm, the docs are a bit lame. You can for example look at the source of `RouterModule` where all kinds of providers are registered https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L142 and how it's imported `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)]` https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule. You don't need to `ROUTES` parameter for your own module.

Comment: I don't understand. Let's make an example : I have a NbNotificationService with my value, a setter and a getter. This service is initially imported in a services.module.ts. Do I have to create a NbNotificationServiceModule to implement forRoot or can I directly do one with the files I have already ?

Comment: Can you please add the code (`@NgModule(...)` of the modules involved in your problem with the relevant provider(s)) to your question and then I'll add a corrected example to my answer if I find a mistake?

Comment: You shouldn't need `providers: [NbNotificationService, ...]` anywhere else than in `forRoot()`, it shouldn't hurt though as long as it is only in modules that are not lazy loaded. The circular dependency problem is independent of the singleton problem. I would need to see more code to be able to make suggestions. Can you try to make a **minimal** reproduction in http://stackblitz.com? Where and how do you import `NbNotificationServiceModule.forRoot()`?

Comment: Can't really do a reproduction without hurting sensible code. The NbNotificationServiceModule.forRoot() is imported in the app.module.ts. 
A little changement tho, there is no more this cyclic problem but now my object is equal to useValue. Can is use this useValue to create my service ?

Comment: "Can't really do a reproduction without hurting sensible code". I can't imagine. No single implementation line is required for that, only class declarations and constructor parameters.

Comment: I haven't even noticed this line with `useValue`. It doesn't look like this is what you intend. When you request `NbNotificationService`, you'll get `0` injected. Is that really the intention? If you want to inject simple values, you should use instead `InjectionToken` https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens

Comment: Idd, I want to inject an instance of my service at this point. Where can I create it ? I suppose I can in the same file do an export

Comment: It's good, the Injection resolve every problem I had ! Thank you so much for the help ! :D

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your notifications in your service, why not simply using a getter ?

#### notification.service.ts

```
notifications: Notification[];
```

#### header.component.ts

```
get totalNotifications() { return this.notificationService.notifications.length; }
```

Comment: The fact is, I don't have any notifications in my service. This service let me handle some errors if some happens and create a notification object in the `notification: BehaviorSubject<Object>`

Comment: Then use the getter with the variable contianing your notifications, and if you need to share it between components, create a service for that

Comment: In a new service, does my variable still need to be a SubjectBehavior or can it be a normal one ?

Comment: No, let it be a "normal" one, this will be way much easier !